# Why is my workflow not triggered by creating a deployment?

Tags: github, github-actions

I created a simple demonstration workflow like this:

```
name: Deploy
on:
  - deployment

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: "echo 'We pretend to deploy to: ${{ github.event.deployment.environment}}'"
```

According to [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#deployment) the workflow should be run:

> Runs your workflow when someone creates a deployment in the workflow's repository.

I created a couple deployments from another workflow using 3rd party action:

[image: list of deployments]

What am I missing? Why the workflow is not triggered?